# How to train neural networks with multi-channel 1D objects?

Tags: python, neural-network, lasagne

The aim is to implement a neural network architecture with multiple channels (i.e. input layers) of 1D objects (e.g. time series). The idea is to apply independent operations in any channel before combining the feature maps of any channel to output the probabilistic prediction.

A potential solution could be to use [Lasagne](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Lasagne is a lightweight wrapper for Theano. It's generally recommended to use this if one needs the flexibility of Theano but don't want to always write neural network layers from scratch.

Does Lasagne offer the tools to implement multiple channels neural networks for 1D objects in python? Is it possible to implement the multiple input layers using `lasagne.layers` or should one create a custom layer with theano?

Answer (score 0):

### 2D convolutions

Multiple channels of time series is literally just a 2D matrix of data, you can imagine it as a picture. You can apply standard convolutional layers for that.

If you want to "to apply independent operations in any channel before combining the feature maps of any channel" then this can be done by configuring the convolution size in the first layer(s) to be narrow (width 1) in the channel dimension, and wide in the dimension of time; and then combine the channels in the following layers.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. However, this procedure assumes that input layers have the same size. Are you able to extend the answer for such case?

Comment: @MLguy yes, multiple channels generally assumes that they are of the same size - if they aren't *too* different, then you just force them to be of the same size with some preprocessing - padding, filling in gaps with reasonable values, stretching values if e.g. one channel is daily and another is weekly then you copy or interpolate the weekly numbers to daily values. But this usually is done outside of the NN system.